# Is there such a thing as a name attribute in tkinter.Button?

Tags: python, tkinter

A while ago, I read in an online article that a 'name' attribute - I call it property, but I've read it written as options in tutorials - could be added to a tkinter.Button list of options. Not been able to find the article again, I decided to post this question here in the hope somebody can shed light on it.
I've tried the following on the idle:

```
from tkinter import *
btn = Button(text='Button', name='keyboard group'); btn.pack()
```

and I got no complaints from it, but when I tried to access the property so:

```
btn['name']
```

I got this:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-name"
```

Since there's no apparent error during its assignement, is it possible to add a name option to the button? In certain cases, I think, it'd be a handy tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a name property, but it is private and starting with `_`. you can access it using `btn._name`